# selecting the highest value on table

Tags: sql, db2

so, i have this query

```
select C.custID, C.custName, count(C.custID) as totalOrder from Customer C, Purchase P
where C.custID = P.custID and P.purchaseDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by C.custID, C.custName
```

this query shows all records of the Customers. how can i modify this query so that it will only show the record of Customer with highest totalOrder ?

i could try using `having count(C.custID) = ...` but then i don't know what else to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-select to do that (and a `JOIN` to further optimize it).

Also, hope I'm not being too annoying but I'm not really sure you should `GROUP BY` the customer ID and name. The ID should be enough. Grouping by both would work if customers can have the same ID and different names. Like `ID 1, Name John` and `ID 1, Name Jeff`. If it does, it should probably not be like that :P

Anyway, I'd recommend trying this one out:

```
SELECT total_orders.custID, total_orders.custName, MAX(total_orders.totalOrder) FROM (SELECT c.custID, c.custName, count(c.custID) as totalOrder FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Purchase p ON c.custID = p.custID WHERE p.purchaseDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' GROUP BY c.custID, c.custName) as total_orders
```

First you select and count the same as before but store that as a sort of *virtual table* (doing the `SELECT ... FROM (<another select>) as something` where `something` is the *virtual table*), from which you select the `MAX(totalOrder)`.

Comment: it doesn't work, sir. it gives me this error;

`An expression starting with "CUSTNAME" specified in a SELECT clause, 
HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or 
it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column 
function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803`

Answer (score 0):

solved. i figured it out to be something like this:

```
select C.custID, C.custName, count(C.custID) as totalOrder from Customer C, Purchase P
where C.custID = P.custID and P.purchaseDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by C.custID, C.custName having count(C.custID) = 
(select max(t.totalOrder) from 
(select C.custID, C.custName, count(C.custID) as totalOrder from Customer C, Purchase P
where C.custID = P.custID and P.purchaseDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by C.custID, C.custName) t)
```

notice that i've added

```
having count(C.custID) = 
(select max(t.totalOrder) from 
(select C.custID, C.custName, count(C.custID) as totalOrder from Customer C, Purchase P
where C.custID = P.custID and P.purchaseDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by C.custID, C.custName) t)
```

so it would find the maximum value of totalOrder. and `count(C.custID)` will be assigned to the maximum value of totalOrder. this might be a quite awful code, but it works.

if anyone has a simpler way to solve this, please do share the code.